# Magento2.3 : Layered Navigation issue

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.3

**When call block on custom view:**

> $layer=$layout->createBlock('Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category');
>
> Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Illegal state
>       #0 /home/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/Interceptor.php(63):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->addFieldToFilter('category_ids',
>   '169')
>       #1 /home/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php(479):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->addFieldToFilter('category_ids',
>   '169')
>       #2 /home/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/Interceptor.php(128):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->addCategoryFilter(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
>       #3 /home/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php(76):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->addCategoryFilter(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
>       #4 /home/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php(67):
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->apply(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>       #5 /home/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(273):
>   Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->_prepareLayout()

Comment: Hello @Phong I have kind of same issue regarding FilterableAttributeListInterface

Comment: So I added preference in di.xml and it worked, Please debug and check which Interface is not defined and set preference of that Interface in di.xml

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-move-layered-navigation-below-category-discription-block/td-p/56057 This will also help.

Comment: Hi @Phong, did you found any solution for this, I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. By removing throw exception, you can solve the issue.
2. Override file if it works in your case

Go to `vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->addFieldToFilter()` function and remove

```
    if ($this->searchResult !== null) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Illegal state');
}
```